# Page layout div structure is changing from the page layout in SP 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, page-layout

I have a page layout with this contents:

```
<%@ Page language="C#" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingLayoutPage,Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePointWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="PublishingWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="PublishingNavigation" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
    <SharePointWebControls:FieldValue id="PageTitle" FieldName="Title" runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
    <SharePointWebControls:TextField runat="server" id="TitleField" FieldName="Title"/>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">





    <div id="OuterZoneTable">

        <div id="OuterLeftCell">

            <div class="ZoneTopC">
                <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" AllowPersonalization="false" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" ID="TopZone" Title="Top Zone" Orientation="Vertical" QuickAdd-GroupNames="Default" QuickAdd-ShowListsAndLibraries="false">
                    <ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate>
                </WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
            </div>

            <div class="ZoneTopA">
                <PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField ID="RichHtmlField1" FieldName="PublishingPageContent" MinimumEditHeight="100px" AllowFontColorsMenu="false"  PrefixStyleSheet="os-" PreviewValueSize="Small" runat="server"/>
            </div>

            <div class="ZoneTopB">
                <PublishingWebControls:SummaryLinkFieldControl FieldName="SummaryLinks"  runat="server"/>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>




</asp:Content>
```

Note the structure of the divs, the 3 inner Zones are all siblings. However when I try this out, the page returns the html structure differently. In the returned html, it comes out to

```
   <div class="ZoneTopC">

       ...

        <div class="ZoneTopA">
           ...
        </div>

       <div class="ZoneTopB">
           ...
        </div>

   </div>
```

I isolated the problem to the `WebPartPages:WebPartZone`. Removing it will cause the div structure to return as I expect, but keeping it causes this glitch.

Does anyone know why this could be happening and know how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Should you add screenshot with your expected and the current issue, I have  read your question three times and can't imagine where's the issue that related to webpart zone ?! also what about ZoneTopC is it parent for A and B as last HTML or as the page layout structure ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" AllowPersonalization="false" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" ID="TopZone" Title="Top Zone" Orientation="Vertical" />
```

Also consider updating your version in the assembly tags to 15.0.0.0 and when editing properties for Page Layout, set UI version to 15.